# JS form validation function is not called inside onsubmit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a form validation on an HTML form with pureJS.

Here is my code:

```
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="alert('hello world');return validateForm(myForm);">
<label>
    <input name="username" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
</label>
<label>
    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit 1">
<button type="submit">Submit 2</button>
<button>Submit 3</button>
```

```
function validateForm(formName) {
  const form = document.forms[formName];
  for(let i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
    const element = form.elements[i];

    // validation fails if element is required and blank
    if(element.attributes["required"] && !element.value.length){
        element.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // validation fails if email is not valid
    if(element.getAttribute('type') === "email" && !validateEmail(element.value)) {
        element.focus();
        return false;
    }
  };

  return true;
}

function validateEmail(str) {
    var regexp = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*/;
    return regexp.test(str);
}
```

new link without typo: http://jsfiddle.net/mech8bon/

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/4bjmh9as/</strike>

**Expected:** to call the alert then the function.

**Result:** nothing called at all.

Comment: Tried adding novalidate?

Comment: Actually this made it work! The function got called once i added that tag. Im trying to make the function more generic to work on any form tag and then will update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Good glad it got solved

Comment: @Ric is novalidate related to html5 and there was a conflict between html5 validation and js validation?

Comment: Novalidate specifies the form is not to be validated when submitted. If you omit this, the required attributes on your inputs force form validation and your js won't get fired

Comment: you didn't mention what the problem is, also I just ran your code and it works, am I missing something ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak The code runs HTML5 validation by default. I needed to do a JS validation which did not get called except when I used novalidation attribute mention by Ric in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Read the error message.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined

---

You are passing the **variable** `myForm`:

> ```
> validateForm(myForm);
> ```

But then you are treating it as a string containing a property name:

> ```
> const form = document.forms[formName];
> ```

String literals need quotes around them:

```
validateForm('myForm');
```

Comment: That was a typo, this is meant to be a string. Though I don't find any errors in the console because the function is not being called at all. I edited the JS fiddle to fix the type.

Comment: @Ghanem — You edited another part at the same time. Now it says `const form = document.forms.formName;` which is different to `const form = document.forms[formName];`. Change it back.

Answer (score 0):

The solution thanks to Ric and Quentin in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eg89b02j/2/

```
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" novalidate>
```

The first fix was adding novalidate attribute to the form tag.

The second fix was making the form more generic by sending the form itself instead of name.